# how to get FileName of process.MainModule?

Tags: c#, .net, process

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process proc in processlist) {
              Console.Write(proc.MainModule.FileName);
}
```

it give an `Win32Exception was unhandled access denied` how to fix this? I tried run it as adm but it get same error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to get the name of a 64-bit process from a 32-bit app?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/3aa75320-0524-4c74-ac3b-2d8aca319c51/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Process.MainModule --> "Access is denied"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431298/process-mainmodule-access-is-denied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some processes that you aren't allowed to access even as administrator.  You can trap the exception and keep going:

```
foreach (Process proc in processlist)
{
  try
  {
    Console.WriteLine(proc.MainModule.FileName);
  }
  catch (Win32Exception e)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(proc.ToString() + "  " + e.Message);
  }
}
```