# A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process using C#

Tags: c#, interop, unhandled-exception

I need to access the active program and Debug the name of the active program but when I use get proccess Id i get that 64 bit proccess can not be accessed by a  32 bit program error

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            IntPtr hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
            uint procId = 0;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out procId);
            var proc = Process.GetProcessById((int)procId);
            Debug.WriteLine(proc.MainModule);
            //Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);



}
```

Comment: Can you compile your application as 64 bit?

Comment: See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52510537/getting-process-information-of-a-64-bit-application-from-32-bit-application

Answer (score 2):

> On 64-bit Windows, a 64-bit process cannot load a 32-bit dynamic-link
> library (DLL). Additionally, a 32-bit process cannot load a 64-bit
> DLL. However, 64-bit Windows supports remote procedure calls (RPC)
> between 64-bit and 32-bit processes (both on the same computer and
> across computers). On 64-bit Windows, an out-of-process 32-bit COM
> server can communicate with a 64-bit client, and an out-of-process
> 64-bit COM server can communicate with a 32-bit client. Therefore, if
> you have a 32-bit DLL that is not COM-aware, you can wrap it in an
> out-of-process COM server and use COM to marshal calls to and from a
> 64-bit process.

[Process Interoperability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/process-interoperability)

**NOTE:**
But actually, this is not your problem. Because of you are calling the `user32.dll`, and depend on how you compile your application as `x86` or `x64` platform, the proper `user32.dll` will be loaded when your application is launched. The system has two versions of the `user32.dll` library: one for x86 applications, an one for x64 applications.

So, there is some problem in your environment or project setting, that not exposed in your question.

Comment: @IanSurii: See `NOTE` in my answer, please.

Comment: This was really helpful .I was compiling as 32 bit .